# Problem with refreshing GridLayout on Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, grid-layout

i have a problem with refreshing the values of my gridlayout.

So, i have a JPanel in a JFrame and in that JPanel , once i entered two values(one for rows and one for columns) and then by clicking on validate, i get a GridLayout with the previous values of JButtons.
So for exemple if I enter (2,2) i get a GridLayout of 4 JButtons and in each JButton i have an image.

So my problem here is, every time i wanna refresh the GridLayout by changing the values, it doesn’t work, the GridLayout doesn’t change, or if it change, the JButtons are inclickable.
I feel like every time i click on Validate, a new GridLayout is created on my JPanel, but the first one is still there.

I will upload two pictures, one with the normal functioning (entering values first time), and the second with the bug (entering new values).

Thanks guys.

[First values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xrCm.png)
[Second values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbYT9.png)

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;




    public class PagePrincipal extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton Valider;
    JTextField Columns;
    JTextField Rows;
    ArrayList<JButton> butt;
   
    
    public PagePrincipal(){
        
        getContentPane().setLayout(null); //this is not the panel that contains the GridLayout
    
        Columns = new JTextField();
        Columns.setBounds(219, 35, 197, 57);
        getContentPane().add(Columns);
        Columns.setColumns(10);
        
        Rows = new JTextField();
        Rows.setBounds(451, 35, 226, 57);
        getContentPane().add(Rows);
        Rows.setColumns(10);
        
        Valider = new JButton();
        Valider.setBackground(new Color(65, 179, 163));
        Valider.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        Valider.setFont(new Font("Bookman Old Style", Font.BOLD, 20));
        Valider.setBounds(704, 15, 268, 81);
        Valider.setText("Validation");
        Valider.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(Valider);

        
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    

    @Override    
   
    
        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

     if (event.getSource() == Valider) {   
        int NbRows= Integer.parseInt(Rows.getText());
        int NbColumns=Integer.parseInt(Columns.getText());
        JButton button[] = new JButton[NbRows*NbColumns];
        butt = new ArrayList<>();
       
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel botPanel = new JPanel(); //this is the panel that contains the GridLayout
        botPanel.setBounds(100, 200, 1000, 400);
        this.add(botPanel);
        
        botPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(NbRows,NbColumns));
        
        for (int i=0; i<NbRows*NbColumns; i++){
                button[i]=new JButton();
                botPanel.add(button[i]);
                butt.add(button[i]);    
        }
        this.setVisible(true);
        
    }
     
        
}
}
```

Comment: `setLayout(null);` That's the first thing that needs fixing. Always use layout managers.

Comment: I'm sorry but i did not understand, where do i have to add setLayout(null)?

Comment: That's the point -- you have already added this, `getContentPane().setLayout(null);`, but you *shouldn't* as it is the layout equivalent of shooting yourself in the foot. Is this your own code or is it found code?

Comment: You also will want to post a minimal code example, one with enough code to compile and illustrate your problem but without all the other code that only complicates and confuses us, a [mre]. Please read the link that explains this most useful tool.

Comment: Yes, this is my code.  getContentPane().setLayout(null) is for the first panel which contains my validate button ect. The panel that contains my buttons and the gridlayout is botPanel, i just changed the code so it can be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: You're still running into huge problems due to your use of null layout for the contentPane. No, it's not the component that you see the problem with, but it is contributing to the problem. Again, don't use null layouts. Nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager. Also, when changing the contents of any container, call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container.

Answer (score 2):

Again, avoid null layouts if at all possible, since they force you to create rigid, inflexible, hard to maintain GUI's that might work on one platform only. Instead, nest JPanels, each using its own layout to help create GUI's that look good, are flexible, extendable and that work.

Also, when changing components held within a container, call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container after making the changes. For example, the following GUI:

[image]

[image]

Is created with the following code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PagePrincipal2 extends JPanel {
    public static final int MAX_ROWS = 40;
    public static final int MAX_COLS = 12;
    private JButton validatorButton = new JButton("Validate");
    private JSpinner columnsSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(2, 1, MAX_COLS, 1));
    private JSpinner rowsSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(2, 1, MAX_ROWS, 1));
    private List<JButton> buttonsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
    
    public PagePrincipal2() {
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Columns:"));
        topPanel.add(columnsSpinner);
        topPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Rows:"));
        topPanel.add(rowsSpinner);
        topPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        topPanel.add(validatorButton);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(gridPanel);
        
        int gridWidth = 1000;
        int gridHeight = 600;
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gridWidth, gridHeight));
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        validatorButton.addActionListener(e -> validateGrid());
    }
    
    private void validateGrid() {
        int nbRows = (int) rowsSpinner.getValue();
        int nbColumns = (int) columnsSpinner.getValue();
        gridPanel.removeAll();
        buttonsList.clear();
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(nbRows, nbColumns));
        for (int i = 0; i < nbRows * nbColumns; i++) {
            int column = i % nbColumns;
            int row = i / nbColumns;
            String text = String.format("[%02d, %02d]", column, row);
            JButton button = new JButton(text);
            button.addActionListener(e -> gridButtonAction(column, row));
            buttonsList.add(button);
            gridPanel.add(button);
        }
        gridPanel.revalidate();
        gridPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    private void gridButtonAction(int column, int row) {
        String message = String.format("Button pressed: [%02d, %02d]", column, row);
        String title = "Grid Button Press";
        int type = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message, title, type);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            PagePrincipal2 mainPanel = new PagePrincipal2();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

---

Note that the gridPanel, the one holding the buttons, is placed into a JScrollPane:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(gridPanel);
```

Note that the main JPanel that holds everything is given a BorderLayout, and then 2 components are added, a topPanel JPanel that holds labels, buttons and fields for data input, added at the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`, the top position, and the JScrollPane is added to the main JPanel at the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

When the old buttons are removed from the gridPanel, and then new buttons are added, I will call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the gridPanel, the first method to get the layout managers to layout the new components, and the second method call to remove any dirty pixels that may be present:

```
private void validateGrid() {
    int nbRows = (int) rowsSpinner.getValue();
    int nbColumns = (int) columnsSpinner.getValue();
    gridPanel.removeAll();
    buttonsList.clear();
    gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(nbRows, nbColumns));
    for (int i = 0; i < nbRows * nbColumns; i++) {
        int column = i % nbColumns;
        int row = i / nbColumns;
        String text = String.format("[%02d, %02d]", column, row);
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(e -> gridButtonAction(column, row));
        buttonsList.add(button);
        gridPanel.add(button);
    }
    gridPanel.revalidate();
    gridPanel.repaint();
}
```